Механизм присваивания и передачи Immutable types (Records) в качестве аргументов функции в C#
В общем в C# мы с коробки имеем единственный неизменяемый тип - string. Во многих учебниках описано, что это гибридный тип, который ведет себя как обычная структура, но при этом является классом. То есть является ссылочным типом и хранится только в куче.
Для удобства работы с этим типом были перегружены и переопределены операторы присваивания таким образом, что если создается копия - то копируется лишь ссылка. А если объект изменяется - то создается новый объект и новая ссылка. Что как бы экономит время копирования и оперативную память.
Еще там упоминалось о том, что это является "альтернатива" интернированию строк, при котором в начальных версиях C# все строки хранились только в 1м экземпляре. Из за чего были сильные потери в производительности на проверку уникальности строки во всем приложении.
Когда я ознакомился с Record типами - то как бы думал, что они работают таким же образом. Но в MSDN ничего об этом не сказано, зато сказано:
Что заставляет сомневаться что они работают также как и string, то есть постоянно копируются при передаче как аргументы.(Потому что тут указаны и изменяемые и неизменяемые Record и нет пометок про string, а значит наверное C# на это вообще не смотрит и это является просто "сахаром", который пишет за вас перегрузки методов и свойств, а не встроенной фичей как у string)
Поэтому у меня вопрос - так ли это? Или они действительно себя ведут как строки?
Дело еще в том, что в описании сказано, что Record могут быть изменяемыми и могут быть по сути классами и структурами, в зависимости от того как объявить тип. Поэтому встречный вопрос - сохраняется ли эта фишка с присваиваниями в каком-то конкретном случае. Где найти ответы на эти вопросы? Или поделитесь вашими знаниями, пожалуйста.
P.S.
Еще знаю такую инфу, что если передача аргумента происходит с меткой 'in' то как бы C# пытается обеспечить неизменяемость и создает копии структур, но при этом если структура является readonly - то копия не создается и структура передается по ссылке. Так что вот такой еще нюанс. И обидно что это в MSDN нигде толком не расписано. (как оно работает с Record)

это всё [почти всё] синтаксический сахар и разные типы обёрток над чем либо, и не более того; и вы можете запросто наделать любых иммутабельных типов - создайте объект/структуру с private-полем с чем вам нужно, а затем задайте логику над обёртками, такую что поля в обёртке неизменны [это значит что вы до полей достучаться не можете, они же private], но логика обёрток порождает как результат - тоже обёртку, вот и получите immutable-тип, т.е. всё это: обёртка + обёртка => обёртка

Лучше не пытайтесь ничего сравнивать со строками. Строки - уникальный тип данных, для него делаются разные специфические оптимизации, поэтому строки лучше изучать как "вещь в себе" и не пытаться понимать другие типы через них.

ровно так же можно сказать и про bool, это обычный иммутабельный тип, в котором на самом деле помещён нативный инт, и задана логика типа, и эта логика порождает bool как операции над такими же bool-ами, bool + bool => bool, а bool - это иммутабельный тип обёртывающий нативный инт

Да это понятно. Просто я думал что там все намного глубже. А если это просто сахар, то получается присваивание перегрузить нельзя и там все по-старому.

тут как бы "не всё по-старому" а много мути) потому что на каждый record нужно собрать собственный тип который собирает компилятор, а тип - это дорого, т.е. если безудержно клепать разнообразные рекорды - компилятор в типах утонет, компилятор не тонет в строках и тех же bool-ах, потому что типы на них не плодит, а вот на рекорды такого наплодит, что лучше не связываться

Ну так какая разница, если не компилятор, то ты их вручную наплодишь. Это Tuple в итоге начинают повторятся и там как бы проблемы такой нет. А рекорды же просто делают работу за тебя, но эти типы в итоге всеравно будут созданы

тут как бы обычно уже имеющихся "системных" типов хватает, и порождать лишние порождения зла - ну это такое себе, а если создаётся такая ситуация что вкрай нужны какие то кортежи и рекорды всякие - тут сильно нужно задуматься и остановиться, потому что явно что-то не так с данными, с организацией данных, с доступом к данным и так далее
